# Queuing Visual Studio Online Build With Powershell

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild, azure-devops

Is there a way to queue a Visual Studio Online "Build Definition" -- versus a "XAML Definition" -- using Powershell.

I have the following script:

```
#// CONFIGURATION ITEMS ============================================
$serverName="https://example.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection"
$username = "example@example.com"
$password = "mypassword";
$teamProject = "Web"
$buildDefinition = "Test"
#// ================================================================


[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client")
$assembly = ("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")

$source =  @"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using System.Net;
public class ConnectByImplementingCredentialsProvider : ICredentialsProvider
    {
        public ICredentials GetCredentials(Uri uri, ICredentials iCredentials)
        {
            return new NetworkCredential(" $username ", " $password ");
        }

        public void NotifyCredentialsAuthenticated(Uri uri)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Unable to authenticate");
        }
    }
"@

Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $assembly -TypeDefinition $source -Language CSharp 
$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($serverName, (New-Object ConnectByImplementingCredentialsProvider))
$tfs.EnsureAuthenticated() 
$buildserver = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])
$definition = $buildserver.GetBuildDefinition($teamProject, $buildDefinition)
$request = $definition.CreateBuildRequest()
$buildserver.QueueBuild($request, "None")
```

... but `GetBuildDefinition()` only returns the items listed under XAML Definitions.  :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated url:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build

Have you tried using VSO REST api to queue a build? See 'request a build' section here - https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/build/requests

Comment: I just tried POSTing to this URL: https://MYACCOUNTNAMEWASHERE.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/Web/_apis/build/requests?api-version=1.0

With a body of:  

`{
  "definition": {
    "id": 1
  },
  "reason": "Manual",
  "priority": "Normal"
}`

I got back this in the response:

_Microsoft Internet Explorer's Enhanced Security Configuration is currently enabled on your environment. This enhanced level of security prevents our web integration experiences from displaying or performing correctly._ 

I am using Google Chrome and Postman on a Mac so I know that message isn't from my side.

Comment: I did a GET using the same URL and it shows me all my builds but again only the XAML Definitions not the ones listed under "Build Definitions"

Comment: Hmm.. that's weird. When sending the post request, how are you authenticating? Assuming you've enabled alternate credentials on your account and are using basic auth? It might be worth to try using PAT (personal access token) as well. You can create a PAT from your profile page in VSO and provide it in the HTTP header of your POST request as `Authorization: Bearer <auth-token>`

Comment: I generated a PAT, and put **Authorization** in the header field and then **Bearer** _mytokenwenthere_ in the value field in Postman.   I still get the same Enhanced Security Configuration message.

Comment: Can you try using version 2.0 of the api? See this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533664/fetching-build-definitions-from-visual-studio-online-through-tfs-api

Comment: That worked.   Now, I need to figure out... how do I translate that into my Powershell Script.

Comment: When I call this from Powershell, I am getting the same authentication issue.   I added the Authentication header, but its still not working.

Comment: The link in the answer above is dead.