# Can't find build definition in TFS 2015

Tags: c#, tfs-2015

I'm playing around with TFS2015 & programmability. I've created a collection and some team projects in it. Furthermore I've created a few build definitions, but when I try to access it programmatically I get an exception, telling me the definition cannot be found.

```
Uri teamCollectionUri = new Uri("http://tfs-playground:8080/tfs/MyCollection");
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(teamCollectionUri);
teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();

IBuildServer buildServer = (IBuildServer)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));

var definition = buildServer.GetBuildDefinition("FakeService", "Build fake service");
```

But when I check the web UI I see that build definition right there. What am I missing here?

Edit:

```
var builds = buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions("FakeService")
```

Doesn't return any build definitions either ?!?

Comment: The FakeService build definition is a non-XAML build definition?

Comment: IBuildServer.GetBuildDefinition (my Project, my Definition name) this will return  build definition with the given name in the given team project. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc339946.aspx  Did your definition meet the demand?

Comment: @ds19 Yes, it's a non-XAML build definition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BuildDefinition null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353000/builddefinition-null)

Comment: You need to use the BuildHttpClient. See my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533664/fetching-build-definitions-from-visual-studio-online-through-tfs-api/37056129#37056129) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353000/builddefinition-null/37056498#37056498).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this for the XAML build definition.You code is accurate without any problem. According to your exception, please just make sure you have added all the reference which needed.

If you want to use this to get VNext build definition. This is not supported, as Daveshaw mentioned. You need to use **Rest API**

```
https://{your-project}.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/taeguk/_apis/build/definitions?api-ver
```

more detailed 
[BuildDefinition null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353000/builddefinition-null)

Update: for the new vNext build, all the old API is not supported by now. The one you can only use is Rest API. This has been a Feature Request submit to Microsoft.

Comment: Very important to keep this post in mind as it saved me a good amount of time. 2.0 API calls are not supported through `TfsTeamProjectCollection`.